# When did Haymitch organize the effort to get Katniss out of the 75th Hunger Games?

Tags: the-hunger-games

How did Haymitch do it? He couldn't have done it via phone, as no doubt the phones would be tapped. It seems like there was little time to organize the rebellion during the few days in the Capital before they were sent to the arena. And in particular the coordination with District 13 seems quite difficult. How did he do it?

I should add that it mentions at the end of the book that it was coordinated from the moment the quell was announced, across many districts, and the capital. Seems difficult to manage, given limited travel and no un-tapped sources...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's implied though never explicitly stated that the rebellion is older and has been building longer than the Quarter Quell. The Victory Tour and the Quarter Quell were in my view the catalysts that brought forward the rebellion, rather than creating it. Many of the pieces were in my opinion already in place. This might explain why Plutarch Heavensbee volunteered for a job that few wanted - he was biding his time for an opportunity. As for Haymitch managing to organise all that he did? He's clever, remember, as well as being well-connected with his friends among the former Games winners. He won his Games with a trick having intuitively worked out how to use the arena against his opponent. And he's spent a lifetime as the bumbling mentor for District 12. The drinking was a coping mechanism, but in my mind it also a became a cloak, a disguise to deflect any suspicion that he many be capable of organising anything of consequence.

Answer (score 2):

I had figured that having known most of the surviving winners for a long time, we was able to gauge their potential willingness to help well before ever arriving at the games.  He is friends, and it sounds like fairly close friends, with a number of them, and so would be able to do this pretty well I think.

Additionally, and I can't really understand why they wouldn't surveil the tributes and entourage leading up to the games, they apparently don't keep them under watch or even listen to them via audio bugs.

This fact opens up at least some time for him to have met with and spoken to like minded winners (and a games master who for the life of me, how the heck did he get identified as a rebellion oriented capital citizen, I would really love to know).  So far as coordination with District 13, it should not have taken much communication to coordinate.  District 13 likely has been monitoring the goings on in Panem for a long time.

Seeing rebellion fomenting among the districts, and then getting even the most brief word through whatever means that a party of rebels is seeking asylum, respite, refit, whatever, I would accept them.  Especially if I was a district that successfully managed to defend myself and survive against the Panem forces.  There is little that Panem could do that would not expose the other districts to the fact that 13 exists still, and given their inability to destroy them previously, I doubt they would do so again when the bulk of their forces are currently putting down an internal rebellion.

Haymitches familiarity with the tributes let him coordinate with them quickly and out from under the less than watchful eye.  District 13 did not really need a lot of information or time to process it to want to let them in.

Comment: For one thing, Wiress and Beetee instruct her how to spot the force fields right under their noses.  Additionally, I recall that a couple of characters said things that would at the very least be considered seditious, but nothing happened to them.  With the surveillance abilities that the capital has at their disposal, judging by how well they can watch the tributes in the games, I find it odd that they could not  watch/listen to them there.